# Querying Semi-structured Field In Snowflake

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I have a table within Snowflake that has a field that is of type varchar but the data in it is structured as json (not ideal, I know). Given the below sample data in this field, how would I return both the "id" value and the "tax_lines.price_set.amount" values in a query from this field?

E.g.

```
{
    "self": [{
        "id": "abcdefg",
        "location": {
            "address1": "11234 street name"
        },
        "tax_lines": [{
            "price": 1.04,
            "price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "1.04",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "1.04",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                }
            },
            "rate": 0.0575,
            "title": "xx STATE TAX"
        }, {
            "price": 0.18,
            "price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "0.18",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "0.18",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                }
            },
            "rate": 0.01,
            "title": "XX COUNTY TAX"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't help that the path `tax_lines.price_set.amount` doesn't exist. First you have an array of two tax lines, so perhaps you want one row per tax line, or both elements in the same row? That's unclear. Then each element contains two different paths that end with an amount, so perhaps you want both? Please update your question with the exact requirements and the exact results that you require.

Comment: @MatBailie yes, one row per tax line and both amounts per line respectively.

Answer (score 2):

by using function [`JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/json_extract_path_text.html)

```
select *
, JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(jsonColumn, 'self[0].id') id
, JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(jsonColumn, 'self[0].tax_lines[0].price_set.presentment_money.amount') amount1
from table
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this gets me closer but I'm getting all nulls returned. I'm sure it has to do with quotations or something but not sure. I tried what you provided but also the below, and then double quotes around the fields. Not sure what else to do...


select
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(Line_Items, '"tax_lines"."price_set"."amount"') amount
from
XYZtable

Comment: it's still coming back with all nulls unfortunately. Very weird!

Comment: the documents says :  `The function returns NULL if the path name does not correspond to any element.` , so make sure the path is correct

Comment: it's still coming back with nulls for every value. my data is structured exactly as I have it in my original post and it seems like that will work but maybe the syntax in that field needs to be updated?

Comment: actually if you check your json , its not a vlid json , missing cloding } at the and and and an extra double quote after  "location""  , so i think if you fix your json structure that works

Comment: also see updated path , was missing a level for amount

Comment: So I just typed it in wrong. I updated it in the original post, wrapped it in a "self" array at the top to see if that would help, and successfully validated it against a json validator and I'm still having the same issue. I can't even pull back the first field "id" even when using "self.id" so I'm really confused. Thanks for sticking with me here. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229954/discussion-between-eshirvana-and-slybitz).

Comment: @slybitz Your self item is an array; `"self": [{`... So, `self[0].id` might be more appropriate. Short answer, as per my comment on your question, you REALLY need to start being Exact.

Comment: @MatBailie To answer your comment on my original question, yes I want one row per tax line. Similarly, using your example with IDs, if I set it to zero (i.e. self[0].id) it only pulls back the first instance within that json. There can be multiple IDs within each the record (the IDs are IDs for line items on an order). How do I return all IDs within that field on multiple lines? Also, I can remove the self array but put it in there as that is the only way I can get anything to return, so far.

Comment: I'm sure there is a much easier way but I figured it all out using a lateral flatten on the join. Thanks for everyone's help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: maybe add lateral flatten answer here for future reference

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [VARIANT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#variant) datatype and [LATERAL FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) to work with this kind of data in Snowflake.

```
select var:self[0]:id::string
  , value:price_set:presentment_money:amount::float
  , value:price_set:shop_money:amount::float
from json_table
  , lateral flatten(input => var:self[0]:tax_lines);
```

would give you the following result:

```
ID         PRESENTMENT_AMOUNT SHOP_MONEY_AMOUNT
abcdefg    1.04               1.04
abcdefg    0.18               0.18
```

Here is the full workbook:

```
create database stackoverflow;

use database stackoverflow;

create or replace table json_table (var variant);

insert into json_table (var)
  select  parse_json('{
    "self": [{
        "id": "abcdefg",
        "location": {
            "address1": "11234 street name"
        },
        "tax_lines": [{
            "price": 1.04,
            "price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "1.04",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "1.04",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                }
            },
            "rate": 0.0575,
            "title": "xx STATE TAX"
        }, {
            "price": 0.18,
            "price_set": {
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "0.18",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                },
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "0.18",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                }
            },
            "rate": 0.01,
            "title": "XX COUNTY TAX"
        }]
    }]
}');

select var:self[0]:id::string
, value:price_set:presentment_money:amount::float
, value:price_set:shop_money:amount::float
from json_table
, lateral flatten(input => var:self[0]:tax_lines);
```